# How narrow is the Measurement Problem in QM?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, paradox, quantum-interpretations

I realize that the "Measurement Problem" is an issue unique to the highly technical field of quantum mechanics. But is it ever discussed in philosophy in relation to more general issues of measurement, such as Zeno's paradoxes, Richardson's coastline paradox, the measurement of temperature, ontology of "points" and "lines," quantities of angels on pins, etc., or perhaps just basic questions of what is required for "measurement" in any form? Can anyone recommend some works on this topic, preferably not too technical.

Comment: I'm not a physicist, but as far as I understand it the measurement problem concerns explaining why the wave function loses continuity upon measurement (or more generally, upon loss of quantum coherence, which may occur for reasons other than measurement - e.g., environment). It is not a problem to do with the act of measurement, rather it is a problem to do with the consequence of measurement.  So I would suggest that there is no relationship between the measurement problem and those cases you have cited.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading up on QM now, so perhaps I'll get to that soon, and I may rephrase my question to leave QM out of it altogether, since my interests are really more general.

Comment: @Nick I disagree that there is literally no relation, the same realism/anti-realism, theory/observation issues come up in connection with quantum measurements as with measurements generally, see e.g. [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-issues/#ApprMeasProb). However, interpreting a relation of the wave function to reality in view of its collapse and the observer's role in measurements raises a host of issues specific to quantum theory that are without analogs in classical settings. [Wallace's review](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0149) is a good reference, see p.4 on the difference.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, my comment is very poorly worded, isn't it.  The way I read the OP was that it suggested that the measurement problem was related to our ability to make an accurate measurement, as in, e.g., the referenced coastline paradox.  It's really only in the last couple of months that I have sat down and attempted to learn the workings of QM even at the most elementary level and I'm obviously still groping in the dark to some extent.  I'll have a look at Wallace's review.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glancing now at the SEP article, but looks QM focussed. I'll need to rephrase my question in terms of measurement generally, setting QM to the side. I'm sure no stone has been left unturned in thinking about the "measurement problem," but I never see it discussed in the context of the long history of paradoxes in philosophy, many of which involve what I would call "measurement" problems. I always feel I'm missing something there.

Comment: A measurement is a subjective comparison of some observation against some knowledge. The term "measurement" in QM usually implies the collapse of the function; that is due to the term "observation" is not applicable at the QM scale (you can't see an electron). So, a _measurement_ essentially implies an _interaction_ subject-object (e.g. observer-electron) which produces something that can be _observed_, while causing a change onto the object under observation.

Comment: @Rodolfo. Thanks, that's a very clear summary. So, any "measurement" can be described  in part as a subject-object "interaction" in which both change, but the ratio of subject-object change is radically altered at the quantum scale. Or, conversely, radically altered at the macro or "visible" scale. Is that a fair generalization? Just trying to picture it in various ways.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander Correct. When two systems interact, they necessarily change (otherwise interaction never took place). You are generalizing the idea that a measurement --either macro or micro-- implies interaction (and change), correct. But systems are not "radically altered at the macro scale". When I look or speak to the wall, it is altered at the _micro_ scale. But it is not altered visibly, at the macro scale. The idea of _macro_ is rational-subjective (subjective for humans), we tend to see static things, although they constantly change, they are never the same at two instants of time.

Comment: Thanks. Helps me think things through. When I say the subject-object "ratio" is shifting at different scales I am thinking of the subject changing at the "macro scale." When I look at the wall the subject is radically altered by perceiving a wall, memory storage of wall, etc., in relation to the imperceptible changes in the object, the wall itself.  But I'm still trying to work it out before thinking about scientific measurements of any sort, let alone QM.